# Creating Scheduled Tasks

Tags: c#, wpf, scheduled-tasks

I am working on a C# WPF project. I need to allow the user to create and add a scheduled task to the Windows Task Scheduler.

How could I go about doing this and what using directives and references do I need as I am not finding much when searching the Internet.

Comment: Every you need is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx. API, examples and explanations on how to achieve what you need programmatically.

Answer (score 253, accepted):

You can use [Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper](https://github.com/dahall/taskscheduler):

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;

class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      // Get the service on the local machine
      using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
      {
         // Create a new task definition and assign properties
         TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
         td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Does something";

         // Create a trigger that will fire the task at this time every other day
         td.Triggers.Add(new DailyTrigger { DaysInterval = 2 });

         // Create an action that will launch Notepad whenever the trigger fires
         td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("notepad.exe", "c:\\test.log", null));

         // Register the task in the root folder
         ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(@"Test", td);

         // Remove the task we just created
         ts.RootFolder.DeleteTask("Test");
      }
   }
}
```

Alternatively you can use [native](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API or go for [Quartz.NET](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5115105/625332) for details.

Comment: Yes, you need to download and reference Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.dll. The link is in the answer.

Comment: Yea sorry I thought I did add the reference but for some reason it wasn't. Sorry about that does work great though. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Dmitry how do you start a task? Do you need to register it with the windows scheduler or something?

Comment: This works a lot better than trying to create it by invoking a command line process

Comment: Is there some way to update the created task like accessing by Task name something.?

Comment: @Dmitry Sorry about the Necrobump, how would I register a one-off task?

Comment: @RhysO You could register the task as normal and as the final action call `schtasks.exe` to remove the task

Comment: I see the reference is for win32, what if I my server is 64bit?

Comment: It is possible to create recurring task with this library?

Comment: Since CodePlex is shutting down in a few months, please take note of the NuGet page for the Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper, at https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskScheduler/.

Comment: Also, for #Ewerton, I don't see why not, since it can be done in the underlying native libraries, or by way of XML documents and schtasks.exe. For #Bassie, you can register the task as a one-off event. By default, tasks are deleted after their last scheduled run, although there exists a flag to override this behavior, and retain the task.

Comment: I ran this code, not as administrator. The task was successfully created. I got a System.UnauthorizedAccessException on the task deletion. Is there any other setup necessary to delete a task? Must it always be done by an administrator?

Comment: Bizarrely, if I change the name from "Test" to something 9 characters or longer, I no longer get this exception.

Comment: Is it possible to call a URL with this library ? I have seen the action types, it supports for exe and mail only.

Comment: @Vivek You could just do chrome.exe [url] (or firefox or iexplore etc.)

Comment: how to specify a specific time to run the task??, code is working very good

Comment: @Seichi thats a namespace element. You should probably not use libraries and try to create software if you do not know the differences between basic language constructs. Get a developer to do the job.

Comment: @specializt how nice of you, thanks for the kind words

Answer (score 41):

This works for me
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ASquare.WindowsTaskScheduler/

It is nicely designed Fluent API.

```
//This will create Daily trigger to run every 10 minutes for a duration of 18 hours
SchedulerResponse response = WindowTaskScheduler
    .Configure()
    .CreateTask("TaskName", "C:\\Test.bat")
    .RunDaily()
    .RunEveryXMinutes(10)
    .RunDurationFor(new TimeSpan(18, 0, 0))
    .SetStartDate(new DateTime(2015, 8, 8))
    .SetStartTime(new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0))
    .Execute();
```