# Task scheduler multilanguage parameter

Tags: windows, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I'm using the schtasks command from C# like this:

`schtasks /create /sc ONCE ...`

This works fine until i get a machine with a other language. For example, a german windows wants something like this:

`schtasks /create /sc EINMAL ...`

I wonder how anyone on this planet can write a working command line for machines with different languages. (BTW: what is the reason for making a command line tool schtasks with language-dependant parameterss?)

So there are two questions:

**1) How can i write a language-independant command line for `schtasks` ?**
**2) Is there a way to set the command line processor's language to english?**

EDIT:
Sorry - i missed something:
- I use .NET framework 2.0
- The target systems are Win7 and also XP. Therefore i can't use the TaskScheduler 2.0 API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler for this.

Please see the detailed answer by Dmitry here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7394955/16522