# Execute function every 5 minutes in background

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have function which reads Data out of an Webservice. With that Data i create Bitmaps. I send the Bitmaps to Panels (Displays)  which displays the created Bitmaps. Manually its working like charm. What i need now is, that my Application run this function every 5 min automtically  in the Backround.

My Application is running under IIS. How can i do that? Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to be depended on asp.net project, but you can use `Cache Callback` to do it.
I have found a nice approach, to do it.
actually i don't remember the link so i'll give you a code that i use:

```
public abstract class Job
{
    protected Job()
    {
        Run();
    }

    protected abstract void Execute();
    protected abstract TimeSpan Interval { get; }

    private void Callback(string key, object value, CacheItemRemovedReason reason)
    {
        if (reason == CacheItemRemovedReason.Expired)
        {
            Execute();
            Run();
        }
    }

    protected void Run()
    {
        HttpRuntime.Cache.Add(GetType().ToString(), this, null, 
            Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, Interval, CacheItemPriority.Normal, Callback);
    }
}

Here is the implementation
public class EmailJob : Job
{
    protected override void Execute()
    {
        // TODO: send email to whole users that are registered 
    }

    protected override TimeSpan Interval
    {
        get { return new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do i have to put that so that my method gets executed automatically?

Comment: I use it on conditions in entire project, but you just need to trigger it once, in global.asax-> Application_Start

Answer (score 3):

An Asp.Net application is not the correct framework for a task like this.

You should probably create a [dedicated service](http://tech.pro/tutorial/895/creating-a-simple-windows-service-in-csharp) for this type of tasks.

Another option is to create a [scheduled task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394806/creating-scheduled-tasks) that will run every X minutes

On a side note, if you ***must*** do this through your asp.net application, I recommend reading on how to [Simulate a Windows Service using ASP.NET to run scheduled jobs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12117/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-using-ASP-NET-to-run-sc)

Comment: Thanks i will have a look at it. Yes, i have to do this in asp.net, because the whole Application is written in asp.net