# How to display form on c# at spcefic time?

Tags: c#, service

I have a c# app form. A form will appear that shows all task to do for the day. This form will appear a half-hour before task start. I want to display this form when the program closes.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite figure out the exact question, but it's clear that you want to be able to display a form at a specific time (I figured this out from the title :-) )

Anyway...there are multiple ways to accomplish this, and it depends on what you are hoping to achieve.

If, for instance, you are planning on the app running all the time, you could have app set up a timer to go off then the specific time occurs and process the timer event.

Or, if you don't plan on the app running all the time, using the Windows task scheduler to automatically start your app at the appropriate time,

If you can provide more information on exactly what you are trying to do, and what constraints you have (and ask Romoku asks...what have you tried, see [this link](http://whathaveyoutried.com) for examples of how to formulate a better question.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a [Windows service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14353/Creating-a-Basic-Windows-Service-in-C) that displays a form at a certain time. This would have to be running all the time.

Or you [schedule a task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394806/creating-scheduled-tasks) for your application before it closes.

Comment: how to create  service  in c# 2010 and use it