# How to make some event on clock time?

Tags: c#, time, scheduler, clock, alarm

I mean I want to make something: for example tomorrow at 6 a.m. ( clock based event )

For now the only variant I see is starting new timer with `TimpeStamp` from `FutureTime - Now`

But this solution looks ugly, specially when I will have many events it will force me to have many timers or somehow make timer process nearly event first and then re-calculate how long to wait on next event. And re-calculate each time when I will push new event to events collection.

Just asking if there is something more sane compared to my solution? Or maybe if there is already some free-for-use lib for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably better to use the Windows Task Scheduler for this.

See here for some details: [Creating Scheduled Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394806/creating-scheduled-tasks)

Comment: But can I execute my code with it? I need to execute my code.

Comment: @Heather It works at the level of running an executable, so you'd write your executable and then set up the task to run your executable at a certain time. The advantage of using Windows Task Scheduler is that things will still run at the right time if the computer has been rebooted inbetween.

Comment: I think that there is https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet ( from link you provided ) that makes exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can create 1 timer to execute every x seconds and iterate over an array of events and check if it needs to execute.

If an event must execute, execute it on a separate thread  to ensure it does not interrupt the timer thread.

### Event class

```
class Event
{
    DateTime TargetDate;
    bool Completed = false;
    IExecuter Executer;
}
```

### The `IExecuter` inteface

```
interface IExecuter
{
    void Execute();
}
```

### Sample `IExecuter` implementation

```
class LogEvent : IExecuter
{
    void Execute(){
         // Log event details to DB or Console or whatever
    }
}
```

### Sample timer loop

```
foreach (Event e in eventArr)
{
    if(e.TargetDate == DateTime.Now && !e.Completed)
        e.Executer.Execute();
}
```