# Possible way to implement client update application without UAC prompt

Tags: c#, .net, client, uac

I need to develop an application that will run on clients. The main focus is to let the application update another -specific- application and be able to monitor own defined states for clients. I'm considering something like a console application with TopShelf because it makes debug a lot easier. However... to install or update this specific application I *must* use a MSI. But if for example I create a process that executes msiexec the client/end user will be prompt with UAC. This is a big issue because clients should be updated unattended. And UAC must stay the way it is : highest level.

I've read a lot of questions/answer concerning UAC prompt... and to be honest I'm starting to doubt my own approach. I was not able to find any question that I could relate to.. so I would appreciate it if someone could give me some good advise, tips, references etc on a possible way to approach this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Task Scheduler job with the "Run with highest privileges" option checked.
You can easily [create this job programatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383765%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), even using a XML configuration file.

This way the user is prompted to allow UAC only once (when first clicking an exe for example).

Comment: Akeefe: Thanks! Creating the job programatically solves my issue. Also interesting for creating a scheduled task: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394806/creating-scheduled-tasks