# Make an event when a file as not arrived after a certain time

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I am coding in c# using filesystem watcher to check a directory. 
How can I say "after 8:00 am if file X is not existing do ....." ?, this have to be verified every day.
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need a `FileSystemWatcher` here. Simply use a `Timer` or [Scheduled tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394806/creating-scheduled-tasks) which runs at 8:00, then check for your file exist and get the job done.

Timer can be used if your application will be running all the time throughout the day *24 x 7*, otherise use latter.

`FileSystemWatcher` is something, that we use to get notifications about change in the file system anytime and not for *checking something exist at particular time*.

**Update:** You can use the `FileSystemWatcher` to get the file update immediately, then process it and also the `Timer` mentioned above which finds whether file hasn't been created till 8.00.

Comment: Unless OP needs to process the file as soon as it arrives and take some action if the file doesn't arrive before specified deadline...

Comment: @Grx70 Anyway that's not mentioned in question.

Comment: @Gr70 Yes that what I am doing. I need to send an email if the file doesn't arrive before a specified deadline. If the file is exist it will be processed , that is why i am using FileSystemWatcher. Sriram sry to not specify that

Comment: @Grx70 But still he needs a timer, and of course `FileSystemWatcher` also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scheduler such as Quartz.Net to start at a certain time of the day, see the site for more details:

http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/