# How to run background task at specific time?

Tags: c#, background-task

I need to run my task every day at 3 pm, but background task builder just take an interval for the task to be repeated.
What is the way to achieve that?
(Windows 8.1 universal App).

Comment: What kind of environment are you targetting? Your question is too generic.

Comment: Would it be possible to make a separate program to do the background task? Then you can just have the windows task scheduler run your background task when you need it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Scheduled Tasks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394806/creating-scheduled-tasks)

Comment: Sorry for bad question.I have read that scheduled taks not available in WINRT.

Answer (score 0):

Look at a scheduling library.

I have used Quartz before with success: http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

Otherwise, a simpler and easier solution if viable, is to have your process run according to a scheduled time by the operating system. Windows supports and encourages [scheduling of tasks](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7).

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to use the regular Windows task scheduler, if that is indeed your environment. I'd tell you how to do this, but it would just be a repeat of a previous answer:
[Creating Scheduled Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394806/creating-scheduled-tasks)

> ```
> using System;
> using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;
>
> class Program
> {
>    static void Main(string[] args)
>    {
>       // Get the service on the local machine
>       using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
>       {
>          // Create a new task definition and assign properties
>          TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
>          td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Does something";
>
>          // Create a trigger that will fire the task at this time every other day
>          td.Triggers.Add(new DailyTrigger { DaysInterval = 2 });
>
>          // Create an action that will launch Notepad whenever the trigger fires
>          td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("notepad.exe", "c:\\test.log", null));
>
>          // Register the task in the root folder
>          ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(@"Test", td);
>
>          // Remove the task we just created
>          ts.RootFolder.DeleteTask("Test");
>       }
>    }
> }
> ```

Comment: If this is in fact a duplicate (Windows environment), the question should be flagged instead of copying the answer.

Comment: You're probably right. I thought the question phrasing was different enough to warrant another answer, but on second thought marking it as duplicate would be more helpful.