# How to schedule console app starting in ASP.NET MVC solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, scheduled-tasks, win32-process

I have a solution, "Site" and "MailProcessor".
Now "MailProcessor" is standalone win32 console app, but I need to schedule it from "Site", with restarting every 10 minutes. How I can do this? Please help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in many ways, and depends on your application logic and server config.

- [Windows Task Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7394955/20126)
- [Quartz scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)
- [Hangfire scheduler](http://hangfire.io/)
- Build your own scheduler in asp.net website.
- [and many others](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23%20Task%20Scheduler)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

Most of the time, I use FluentScheduler, du to its simplicity.