# How to set Trigger Type as Logon in task scheduler c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, taskscheduler

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394806/creating-scheduled-tasks)
was perfect for me but i m unable to set TriggerType property to TaskTriggerType.Logon. As error description say its a read only. 
How do i can set this property so that my exe runs everytime when users login?

I need Logon Event with one time scheduled.

Comment: Aren't there specific concrete types for each type of trigger? So, rather than creating a `DailyTrigger` and then changing it's type, wouldn't you create a `LogonTrigger`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Yes i was about to comment that by updating my code to td.Triggers.Add(new LogonTrigger() { Enabled = true }); works correctly.  Thanks for your comment