# TaskService not working

Tags: c#, taskscheduler, taskservice

I'm trying to write some code that uns the task on my local workstation after a certain period of time but at the moment I'm having problems getting the work to be done.

Below is the code I am running.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;

namespace TaskSchedularExamplw
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task Started");
            using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
            {
                TaskDefinition t = ts.NewTask();
                t.Triggers.Add(new TimeTrigger() { StartBoundary = DateTime.Now, Enabled = true });
                t.Principal.LogonType = TaskLogonType.InteractiveToken;
                TimeTrigger tt = (TimeTrigger)t.Triggers.Add(new TimeTrigger() { StartBoundary = DateTime.Now, Enabled = true });
                tt.Repetition.Duration = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
                tt.Repetition.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
                t.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe", "c:\\test.txt", null));
                const string taskName = "Test";
                ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(taskName, t);
                var runningTasks=ts.GetRunningTasks();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me what exactly is I am doing wrong here.

Comment: You provide no error message. "Doesn't work" is not something we can help you with.

Comment: It does not give any error message.It just does not do anything,

Comment: Okay it runs. The problem was that I didn't trigger it.

Answer (score 2):

According to the `TaskService` [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383448(v=vs.85).aspx), you should call the [Connect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383451(v=vs.85).aspx) method before invoking any other of the `TaskService` methods.

> The TaskService.Connect method should be called before calling any of
>   the other TaskService methods.

Comment: "Connects to a remote machine and associates all subsequent calls on this interface with a remote session." But I am not connecting to a remote machine

Comment: @AdityaKorti what is your error message? What is not working? Also, please see this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394806/creating-scheduled-tasks

Comment: It does not give any error message.It just does not do anything, And I had seen that question.But I don't know why it tells to delete the task in the end.

Comment: @AdityaKorti I don't have access right now to a dev machine. I'll test and fix it when I'll get home at the evening.

Comment: Okay it runs. The problem was that I didn't trigger it.

Comment: Great, please submit a new answer with what you did :)