# How to create a routine scheduled in ASP.NET WebApi

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

in my webApi Project i have this situation, when the user inserts data on DataBase it has a expires limite, which means, in "3" days all information about this certain user has to be gone, but i'm not sure how to handle this, I need to create something that stays running in background checking the current date and the expiration date. I found something about it, but it's not quite what I want [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394806/creating-scheduled-tasks) Thanks!

Comment: Use the SQL Server Jobs or Windows Task Scheduler to run housekeeping tasks. Or if you want it all inside your web app, take a look at [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/), it's awesome and free.

Comment: @DavidG thanks, I'll try!

Comment: Along with Hangfire, you should also consider Quartz.NET and FluentScheduler.