# Run Method in TaskService C# ?

Tags: c#, task, console-application, taskservice

I want to execute a function in given date just once and i'm done with the `Task`.
What should i do?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DateTime date = GetExecuteTime();        
    using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
    {
        // Create a new task definition and assign properties
        TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();

        td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "run method";

        TimeTrigger d = new TimeTrigger();
        d.StartBoundary = date;

        td.Triggers.Add(d);

        //td.Actions.Add();
    }

    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create console app, place it somewhere on your machine ,and create event in Task Scheduler and add a trigger when u want to run it.

U can set trigger form another application , you can find answer here:

> [Creating Scheduled Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394806/creating-scheduled-tasks)

Notice , you can't run some random function from your application without running the whole app from Task Scheduler.