# Create Task Scheduler programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, windows, scheduled-tasks

I want to make the Task Scheduler programmatically.
Is there a way to include the [exported task](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/how-to-export-a-task-from-task-scheduler/) from Task Scheduler into C# code to automate task creation?

Comment: Such questions are already there in stack overflow. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394806/creating-scheduled-tasks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Scheduled Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394806/creating-scheduled-tasks)

Comment: Hi @ManishM if you fee la question is a duplicate please flag it as such. See [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [TaskScheduler 2.8.4 NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskScheduler/2.8.4), like this :

```
TaskService.Instance.RootFolder.ImportTask("IDM", @"D:\Update.xml");
```

Comment: I try that, but in my Task Scheduler, I don't see the created task. Why?

Comment: @NemanjaAndric Sorry for wrong package name, i fix my answer.

Comment: @ Mojtaba Tajik I install exactly that package. The last version. But nothing happened. Can you also test this, to help me to solve this problem? I will appreciate that. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @NemanjaAndric I test it and it work. adding task to scheduler need administrator permission, do you run your program as admin ?

Comment: Also if we want to stop task by name, we can do that with this code:
TaskService.Instance.FindTask("FlexiAppServerSeviceMonTask").Stop();