# C# check if Datetime.now is a specific time

Tags: c#

i want to check if the current time is a specific time 
so for example if the current time is `13:13:13` it would beep

```
var xx = new DateTime(2018,10,8,13,19,50);

while (true)
{
    if (DateTime.Now == xx)
        Console.Beep();
}
```

but it is not working

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: You actually check if `DateTime.Now == 2018-10-18 13:19:50.0000000` there's a *small probability* of `Beep`

Comment: @Sham it isn't beeping

Comment: And he gets a 100% Core usage

Comment: @fubo yes i do .

Comment: You probably need to make it compare only down to the seconds value, otherwise the milliseconds will be unlikely to match.

Comment: I would use a scheduled task for this or, if you can't use them, a  System.Timers.Timer. You just have to calculate the time from now until this specific time. Then handle it's [`Elapsed` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.elapsed?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: you can check for an interval, e.g. Math.Abs(DateTime.Now.Subtract(xx).TotalSeconds) <= 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your CPU a break.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var target = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);  // test data

    var aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer((target - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds);
    aTimer.Elapsed += (s, e) => { Console.Beep(); };
    aTimer.Enabled = true;

    Console.WriteLine("Wait a minute...");
    // time to do something useful
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Do not forget to `Dispose` the `Timer` instance: `aTimer.Elapsed += (s, ee) => {(s as System.Timers.Timer)?.Dispose(); Console.Beep(); };`

Comment: Yes, a using block would have been the better practice. Although I don't think this Timer really needs it, it's more a formality form its base class. And we are at the end of Main anyway.

Answer (score 1):

When checking for `==` you actually compare *ticks*: if

```
 DateTime.Now == 2018-10-18 13:19:50.0000000
```

and thus there's only a *tiny* probability to go off `Beep`:

```
 ...
 DateTime.Now == 2018-10-18 13:19:49.9999852
 DateTime.Now == 2018-10-18 13:19:49.9999989 // Transition: no beep here
 DateTime.Now == 2018-10-18 13:19:50.0000007 // infinte loop from now on
 ...
```

Try different test (*quick patch*; `Timer` is a better solution):

```
    var xx = new DateTime(2018,10,8,13,19,50);

    while (true)
    {
        // If DateTime.Now exceeds xx 
        if (DateTime.Now >= xx) {
            // bee..eep
            Console.Beep();

            // and break the loop  
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that this code should be periodically run by a timer rather than a `while` loop too, unless the objective is to indirectly heat their workspace.

Comment: i guess that solves my issue i'll use a timer next time thanks a lot

Comment: @TimSchmelter i just tried to do this with a datetime justt to see if it was possible it isn't part of an app

Answer (score 0):

Time can be divided into really, really small fractions. You need to decide the resolution of time you're okay with. Should it beep if it is the same time down to the second? Or should it be the same time down to the millisecond? Or the nanosecond?

Once you've decided on this, you need to declare your xx value down to that precision, and in the loop, truncate DateTime.Now to the required precision. Then your comparison will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches.

- You could use the task scheduler [Creating Scheduled Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394806/creating-scheduled-tasks)
- or could use Quartz.Net [Cron with Quartz](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/crontriggers.html)
- or just make a sleep:

  var xx = new DateTime(2018,10,8,13,19,50);

  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(xx - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds);

  Console.Beep();