# Schedule telegram bot to send message?

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

I can't just do this

```
public static void myBot_OnMessage(object sender, Telegram.Bot.Args.MessageEventArgs msg)
{
    if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 01)
    {
        myBot.SendTextMessageAsync(msg.Message.Chat.Id, "Good Night");
    }
}
```

Because that requires the user to first send a message at that exact time for them to receive the message. How can i make it autosend a message at a specific to anyone who ever started it without the person having to send message the exact time it would send the automatic message?

Answer (score 0):

You should schedule a task by using the provided interface by Windows.
Also, you should store the ID's of the users in a database and iterate over them every time the scheluded task is running.

You can find more about task scheduling in C# here [Creating Scheduled Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7394806/4957976)

Answer (score 0):

If you developing using .net core you can use [IHostedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice) for realization background task. Also there exist a libraries for sheduled tasks. I recomend [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/).
It's free and easy for use. You can add task like this:

```
var nextDay = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
var sendDate = new DateTime(nextDay.Year, nextDay.Month, nextDay.Day, 1,0,0);
var jobId = BackgroundJob.Schedule(
   () => myBot.SendTextMessageAsync(msg.Message.Chat.Id, "Good Night");
   (sendDate - DateTime.Now));
```

You need database for using Hangfire.