# C# and ASP.NET timer function that runs sql only once a week

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

I have just started learning asp.net and C#. I need to create a function that runs once a week, every Monday and returns a new entry in my SQL database.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I should approach this? And are you aware of any ways to have this kind of functionality without a data log table that checks if the function has already been run for that week?

Comment: Look at Quartz.  It's a scheduling nuget package.

Comment: Hey, maybe this question can help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394806/creating-scheduled-tasks

Comment: If you work with Windows Server you can use the Task Scheduler and make it run your programm once a week.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/system-management-components/schedule-server-process

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Try Hangfire - it can schedule a job and repeat it.

Answer (score 0):

There are some solutions to do this.
Check this out:
[https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-to-run-background-tasks-in-aspnet][1]