# execute a schedule with quartz in visual start now with interval 24 hours

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, quartz-scheduler

I create a crawler that gets the news from the other website that i defined before for it ,so i use `quartz` to run a task in background.the schedule is defined like this :

```
public class JobBackground : IJob

        {

            public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= 920; j++)
                {


                    NewsRepository newsRepository = new NewsRepository();
                    GoyaAgent Goyaagent = new GoyaAgent();
                    Task<List<NewsContent>> lst = Goyaagent.parsing("http://www.gooyait.com/page/"+j);
                    List<NewsContent> enresult = lst.Result;
                    foreach (NewsContent newsContent in enresult)
                    {
                        News newnews = new News();
                        newnews.Subject = newsContent.Title;
                        newnews.NewsDate = DateTime.Now;
                        newnews.NewsBrief = newsContent.abs;
                        newnews.NewsText = newsContent.Content;
                        newnews.ShowOnSlide = "Yes";
                        newnews.GroupId = 1049;
                        newnews.NewsImageSmall = newsContent.Img;
                        newnews.NewsImageBig = newsContent.Img;
                        newnews.Reference = newsContent.Url;
                        newnews.UserId = "3";
                        newnews.Visible = "Yes";
                        newnews.ViewCounter = 0;
                        newsRepository.Add(newnews);
                        if (newsRepository.FindBy(i => i.Reference == newsContent.Url).Count() == 0)

                            newsRepository.Save();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

The `parsing` function :

```
 public async Task<List<NewsContent>> parsing(string newsArchive)
        {
            List<NewsContent> lstResult = new List<NewsContent>();

                try
                {
                    HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
                    var response = await http.GetByteArrayAsync(newsArchive);
                    String source = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8").GetString(response, 0, response.Length - 1);
                    source = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(source);
                    HtmlDocument resultat = new HtmlDocument();
                    resultat.LoadHtml(source);

                    List<HtmlNode> toftitle = resultat.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where
                        (x =>
                         (x.Name == "div" && x.Attributes["class"] != null &&
                          x.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("main-col"))).ToList();
                    var li = toftitle[0].Descendants().Where
                        (x =>
                         (x.Name == "div" && x.Attributes["class"] != null &&
                          x.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("base-box blog-post"))).ToList();

                    foreach (var item in li)
                    {
                        NewsContent newsContent = new NewsContent();
                        newsContent.Url = item.Descendants("a").ToList()[0].GetAttributeValue("href", null);
                        newsContent.Img = item.Descendants("img").ToList()[0].GetAttributeValue("src", null);
                        newsContent.Title = item.Descendants("h2").ToList()[0].InnerText;
                        newsContent.abs = item.Descendants("p").ToList()[0].InnerText;
                        //finding main news content
                        var response1 = await http.GetByteArrayAsync(newsContent.Url);
                        String source1 = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8").GetString(response1, 0, response1.Length - 1);
                        source1 = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(source1);
                        HtmlDocument resultat1 = new HtmlDocument();
                        resultat1.LoadHtml(source1);
                        HtmlNode doc = resultat1.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='entry-content']");
                        HtmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='yasr-visitor-votes']");
                        if (node != null)
                            node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
                        HtmlNode node1 = doc.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='post-tags']");
                        if (node1 != null)
                            node1.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node1);
                        HtmlNode node2 =
                            doc.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='mom-social-share ss-horizontal border-box']");
                        if (node2 != null)

                            node2.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node2);
                        HtmlNode node3 = doc.SelectSingleNode("//script|//style");
                        if (node3 != null)

                            node3.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node3);

                        newsContent.Content = doc.InnerHtml;



                        lstResult.Add(newsContent);


                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
                return lstResult;
        }
```

The schedule starts with this code :

```
  public class JobScheduler
        {
            public static void Start()
            {
                IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
                scheduler.Start();

                IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<JobBackground>().Build();

                ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().StartNow()
                    .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
                      (s =>
                         s.WithIntervalInHours(24)
                        .OnEveryDay()
                        .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(0, 0))
                      )
                    .Build();

                scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
            }
        }
```

There are several problems :

When i run this code the code never executed because of`ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().StartNow()` so i have to wait for 24 hours to see the result why ?

And the second problem ,when i upload the code to the web server it doesn't work .why ?

Comment: @MuratYıldız no it wasn't ,i have to check the url by a console program to make my schedule alive

Comment: You do not have to use console program if you fully read my answer below and follow the steps mentioned on it. I use this approach for sending notification emails once a week and it works like a charm. So, it might not be answer of your question, but I think it is really useful not only for you but also for those who suffered from such a kind of Quartz.Net problem.

Comment: @MuratYıldız you know the main problem is how can make a service alive .after a long time if no one check the site ,the quartz is going to be down.

Comment: I know the problem from the beginning, but you seems to not read my answer completely. So, if you read it and apply step by step the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your method as shown below:

```
public class JobScheduler
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
        scheduler.Start();

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<JobBackground>().Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
            .StartNow()
            .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder
            .DailyAtHourAndMinute(0,0)
                .WithMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed() //MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_NOW
                .InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GTB Standard Time")) //(GMT+02:00) 
                //https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/01/20/using-quartz-net-to-schedule-jobs-in-windows-azure-worker-roles/
                )
            .Build();
        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
}
```

Regarding to the second issue, the problem is related to `IIS` rather than the schedulers `Quartz.NET`, `Hangfire`, etc. On the other hand, there are lots of solution methods posted on the web, but only some of them is working. In my opinion, there is no need to apply lots of configuration settings. Just install [Keep Alive Service For IIS 6.0/7.5](https://keepalive.codeplex.com/) on the server to which you publish your application and enjoy. Then your published application will be alive after application pool recycling, IIS/Application restarting, etc.

**Update:**

Here is the fully working code I have used for months on IIS without any problem. On the other hand, for IIS based triggering problems, have a look at my answer on [Quartz.net scheduler doesn't fire jobs/triggers once deployed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196717/quartz-net-scheduler-doesnt-fire-jobs-triggers-once-deployed/33672149#33672149).

***Global.asax:***

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    JobScheduler.Start();
}
```

***EmailJob.cs:***

```
using Quartz;

public class EmailJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        SendEmail();
    }
}
```

***JobScheduler.cs:***

```
using Quartz;
using Quartz.Impl;

public class JobScheduler
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
        scheduler.Start();

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<EmailJob>().Build();
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
            //.StartAt(new DateTime(2015, 12, 21, 17, 19, 0, 0))
            .StartNow()
            .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder
                .WeeklyOnDayAndHourAndMinute(DayOfWeek.Monday, 10, 00)
                //.WithMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing() //Do not fire if the firing is missed
                .WithMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed() //MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_NOW
                .InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GTB Standard Time")) //(GMT+02:00)
                )
            .Build();
        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please also have a look at [Scheduled Tasks In ASP.NET With Quartz.Net](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/254/scheduled-tasks-in-asp-net-with-quartz-net) and let me know if it works? Try to use short period i.e 5 min. for testing procedures.

Comment: public static void Start()
            {
                IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
                scheduler.Start();

                IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<JobBackground>().Build();

                ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().StartNow()
                  
                    .Build();

                scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
            }

Comment: I finally change it to this ,when i upload it,it works ,but after some minute ,it is stoped

Comment: So you mean i definitely install the servicealive ?